# Remove plugin (interceptor)

Tags: magento2, plugin, interceptor

I want to prevent a certain plugin from loading, namely 'authorization' plugin in

`module-quote/Model/GuestCartManagement/Plugin/Authorization.php`.

What i tried to do is to comment lines in di.xml where this plugin seems to be declared. After i modified the files, i removed *var/generation*, and *var/di* folders, cleared cache and ran `grunt exec`.
 These lines are in:

```
magento/vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml
magento/vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi_soap/di.xml
```

Unfortunately, plugin still keeps loading according to what xdebug shows me:[image]

So, how do i prevent the plugin from loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable a plugin, set `disabled` element to `true`. The default value is `false`.

Use `disabled` property to disable the core or third-party plugins in your `di.xml` file

You can reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html for more information.

Comment: Oh, i read this several times but never saw this line about disabling. Thanks a lot!